# Передача переменной в встроенный скрипт JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, как встроенный скрипт получает переменные из окна, то есть я хотел сделать так:

```
<script src="script.js">var A = 123;</script>
```

а script.js тем временем получает переменную A:

```
alert(A);
```

Но так не работает. Интересен вариант без записи полного скрипта внутри тэга script, а только передача нужных переменных, с которыми скрипт может работать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag не оно?

Comment: Если указан src разве инструкции внутри script не игнорируются?

Comment: @Jean-Claude я не знаю, не интересовался этим никогда.

Comment: @NikolaTesla сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: @NikolaTesla оно, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я бы наверное завернул все-таки в анонимные функции, и экспортировал переменную в глобальный объект, так будет более правильнее на мой взгляд, т.к. в любом случае, писать скрипт или библиотеку в глобальной области видимости не комильфо.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(exports){
      exports.a = 3; 
    })(window);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(exports){
      console.log(exports.a);
    })(window);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

При указанном параметре `src` содержимое тега `<script>` будет проигнорировано.

```
<script src="script.js">alert('Не будет выведено');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно примерно так

```
<script>var A = 1;</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

А внутри script.js обращаться к глобальной переменной А.

Но так делать конечно, если по другому никак или проект очень простой.